# Prove that $f:R\to R$ is differentiable: $x\mapsto x^2, x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Prove that $f:R\to R$, $x\mapsto\begin{cases}x^2,&\text{if }x<0\\x^3,&\text{if }x≥0\end{cases}$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative.

Any tips?

Comment: Hint: there is really only one point you need to worry about (so long as you know that polynomials are differentiable). (And for a good follow-up exercise, change $x^2$ to $x^a$ and $x^3$ to $x^b$ and find all real values of $a$ and $b$ so that $f$ will be continuous, differentiable, continuously differentiable, and smooth.)

Comment: When $x\neq0$, can you show that the function is differentiable? After that, explore the point $x=0$ by using the left hand derivative and right hand derivative and try to conclude from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing that $f$ is differentiable at $x\neq0$ is trivial. Now show that

$$f_{+}'(0)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{(0+h)^3-0^3}{h}=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-}\frac{(0+h)^2-0^2}{h}=f_{-}'(0)$$